# Redirecting after login with the user id

Tags: php, mysql, authentication

I am trying to make this script work as follows...

After a user is logged in they go to the following link index.php?id=1 (userid)

but i have tried many methods here is the following code

```
<?php 
// Include required MySQL configuration file and functions 
require_once('config.inc.php'); 
require_once('functions.inc.php'); 

// Start session 
session_start(); 
  $_SESSION['user_id']= $id;
// Check if user is already logged in 
if ($_SESSION['logged_in'] == true) { 

              // If user is already logged in, redirect to main page 
              redirect('../index.php'); 
} else { 
              // Make sure that user submitted a username/password and username only consists of alphanumeric chars 
              if ( (!isset($_POST['username'])) || (!isset($_POST['password'])) OR 
                   (!ctype_alnum($_POST['username'])) ) { 
                            redirect('../login.php'); 
              } 

              // Connect to database 
              $mysqli = @new mysqli(DB_HOSTNAME, DB_USERNAME, DB_PASSWORD, DB_DATABASE); 

              // Check connection 
              if (mysqli_connect_errno()) { 
                            printf("Unable to connect to database: %s", mysqli_connect_error()); 
                            exit(); 
              } 

              // Escape any unsafe characters before querying database 
              $username = $mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['username']); 
              $password = $mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['password']);

              // Construct SQL statement for query & execute 
              $sql              = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = '" . $username . "' AND password = '" . md5($password) . "'"; 
              $result = $mysqli->query($sql); 

              // If one row is returned, username and password are valid 
              if (is_object($result) && $result->num_rows == 1) { 
                            // Set session variable for login status to true 
                            $_SESSION['logged_in'] = true; 
                            redirect('../index.php?id=' . $_SESSION['user_id']);
              } else { 
                            // If number of rows returned is not one, redirect back to login screen 
                            redirect('../login.php'); 
              } 
} 
?>
```

this isn't a live project or never will be its for my learning curve only.

the current code goes to the following link index.php?id=

---

Updated code after CD001's answer

```
<?php 
// Include required MySQL configuration file and functions 
require_once('config.inc.php'); 
require_once('functions.inc.php'); 

// Start session 
session_start(); 

// Check if user is already logged in 
if ($_SESSION['logged_in'] == true) { 
              // If user is already logged in, redirect to main page 
              redirect('../index.php'); 
} else { 
              // Make sure that user submitted a username/password and username only consists of alphanumeric chars 
              if ( (!isset($_POST['username'])) || (!isset($_POST['password'])) OR 
                   (!ctype_alnum($_POST['username'])) ) { 
                            redirect('../login.php'); 
              } 

              // Connect to database 
              $mysqli = @new mysqli(DB_HOSTNAME, DB_USERNAME, DB_PASSWORD, DB_DATABASE); 

              // Check connection 
              if (mysqli_connect_errno()) { 
                            printf("Unable to connect to database: %s", mysqli_connect_error()); 
                            exit(); 
              } 

              // Escape any unsafe characters before querying database 
              $username = $mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['username']); 
              $password = $mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['password']); 

              // Construct SQL statement for query & execute 
              $sql              = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = '" . $username . "' AND password = '" . md5($password) . "'"; 
              $result = $mysqli->query($sql); 

              // If one row is returned, username and password are valid 
             if (is_object($result) && $result->num_rows == 1) { 
    $iUserId = null;
    $oUser = $result->fetch_object();

    //there's only 1 record but what the hey
    while($oUser = $result->fetch_object()) {
      $iUserId = (int) $oUser->id; // assuming the field in the user table is called `id`
    }

    // Set session variable for login status to true 
    if(!is_null($iUserId)) {
      $_SESSION['logged_in'] = true; 
      redirect('../index.php?id=' . $iUserId);
    }

    //error trapping


              } else { 
                            // If number of rows returned is not one, redirect back to login screen 
                            redirect('../login.php'); 
              } 
} 
?>
```

when i try to login it gives me a error

\includes\login.inc.php on line 10

line 10 is this

```
if ($_SESSION['logged_in'] == true) {
```

Comment: Try changing `if ($_SESSION['logged_in'] == true)` to `if (!empty($_SESSION['logged_in']))` ... if `$_SESSION['logged_in']` hasn't been set PHP may throw a warning as what you're trying to do is evaluate that session variable to being `true` rather than checking to see if it exists AND evaluates to being true (which is what PHP's `empty()` function is for). See: http://www.php.net/empty

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've got:

```
// If one row is returned, username and password are valid 
if (is_object($result) && $result->num_rows == 1) { 
            // Set session variable for login status to true 
            $_SESSION['logged_in'] = true; 
            redirect('../index.php?id=' . $_SESSION['user_id']);
}
```

But at the top of the document you're defining:

`$_SESSION['user_id']= $id;`

However, $id is not actually defined at that point in time unless it's included in one of the required files at the top of the document (which I think unlikely).

You should be retrieving the user id from your database result object (`$result`).

Something like:

```
// If one row is returned, username and password are valid
if (is_object($result) && $result->num_rows == 1) { 
    $iUserId = null;
    $oUser = $result->fetch_object();

    //there's only 1 record but what the hey
    while($oUser = $result->fetch_object()) {
      $iUserId = (int) $oUser->id; // assuming the field in the user table is called `id`
    }

    // Set session variable for login status to true 
    if(!is_null($iUserId)) {
      $_SESSION['logged_in'] = true; 
      redirect('../index.php?id=' . $iUserId);
    }

    //error trapping
    else {
      //throw an Exception or something to trap the invalid user id
    }
}
```

For the mysqli_result object, see:
http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.mysqli-result.php

Especially the methods:
http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-assoc.php
http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-object.php

The mysqli_result object essentially holds the whole resultset, you need to loop through it to get the individual records - though you've as you've only got 1 record you could use:

```
$result->data_seek(0);
$oUser = $result->fetch_object();
$iUserId = (int) $oUser->id; //assuming the user id field is called 'id'
```

As an aside: it's arguably better practice to just have the SQL query match on the username though and retrieve the id and password - and then evaluate the password in the application rather than the database; it further reduces the chance of injection attacks working and means you can better encrypt your password with a hashing and salting object in the application.

Comment: I understand what your saying,  please could you show me the best way to achieve this.

Comment: Sorry - I was tweaking the answer to include a modified version of your code when you posted the comment, the update should cover it.

Comment: Thanks for your reply i am still having a issue it throws a error on line 10 i will update my question with the current code maybe its something i have done wrong

Answer (score 1):

If no text has been written on the page with ECHO php function, then try :

```
header("Location: http://www.google.ca");
```

And you have to replace the url by whatever you need.